# How to fix "No Application ID has been Found" error in e4 application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have been searching for a while now and can still not find a solution to my problem. I have an e4 application that whenever I try to launch it, I get a `No application id has been found` error with not much more information other than that. I have tried adding required plug-ins in both the .product file as well as the run configuration, including adding the optional dependencies.

I am completely stuck trying to get this application to run, it seems to run on my co-worker's computer, but does not want to run on mine. I will paste my error log below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
!SESSION 2016-01-21 14:01:56.955 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_66
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product ExampleApp.product -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -product ExampleApp.product -data C:\Users\e296040\workspace/../runtime-ExampleApp.product(1) -dev file:C:/Users/e296040/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/ExampleApp.product (1)/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2016-01-21 14:02:00.912
!MESSAGE Product ExampleApp.product could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-21 14:02:01.088
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\Users\e296040\runtime-ExampleApp.product(1)\.metadata\.log.
```

**EDIT**

Here is the plugin.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            name="ExampleApp"
            application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
         <property
               name="lifeCycleURI"
               value="bundleclass://ExampleApp/exampleapp.CyamsInitiator">
         </property>
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="ExampleApp">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

**Manifest.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ExampleApp
Bundle-SymbolicName: CyAMSApp;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: exampleapp.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/crystalproject.jar,
 lib/idw-gpl.jar,
 lib/jasypt-1.9.1.jar,
 lib/jcommon-1.0.20.jar,
 lib/jedit.jar,
 lib/jfreechart-1.0.16.jar,
 lib/jgraphx.jar,
 lib/junit-4.11.jar,
 lib/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar,
 lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar,
 lib/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar,
 lib/websocket-ri-bundle-1.0.jar,
 lib/worldwind/gdal.jar,
 lib/worldwind/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar,
 lib/worldwind/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar,
 lib/worldwind/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar,
 lib/worldwind/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar,
 lib/worldwind/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar,
 lib/worldwind/gluegen-rt.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl-all.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl-natives-windows-amd64.jar,
 lib/worldwind/jogl.jar,
 lib/worldwind/worldwind.jar,
 lib/worldwind/worldwindx.jar,
 lib/xstream/jettison-1.2.jar,
 lib/xstream/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar,
 lib/xstream/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar,
 lib/xstream/xstream-1.4.7.jar
Import-Package: org.eclipse.emf.common.notify,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource,
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.osgi.service.event;version="1.3.1"
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.104.0",
 org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="3.11.0",
 org.eclipse.emf.common;bundle-version="2.11.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt;bundle-version="0.13.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt;bundle-version="0.13.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bundle-version="1.3.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench;bundle-version="1.1.100",
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.services;bundle-version="2.0.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts;bundle-version="1.4.0",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.11.0",
 javax.inject;bundle-version="1.0.0";visibility:=reexport
```

**ExampleApp.product**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="ExampleApp" uid="CyAMSApp" id="ExampleApp.product" application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" version="1.0.0.1" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">


   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-clearPersistedState
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>


   <launcher>
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>


   <vm>
      <windows include="false">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8</windows>
   </vm>


   <plugins>
      <plugin id="ExampleApp"/>
      <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
      <plugin id="javax.annotation"/>
      <plugin id="javax.inject"/>
      <plugin id="javax.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="javax.xml"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util.gui"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.jxpath"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.variables"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.events"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.smil"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.svg"/>
   </plugins>


   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

Comment: !MESSAGE Product ExampleApp.product could not be found

Comment: @Rishabh I do not know what is happening, becuase I am trying to run the application from that exact file

Comment: May be you should not directly add the file into workspace. It will be better to replicate the project structure and create classes.

Comment: @Rishabh I am not entirely sure I follow what you mean, could you please explain a bit more

Comment: The .product file is not what defines the product id. Show us the plugin.xml for your RCP plugin.

Comment: @greg-449. I have added that file here

Comment: Is the project name and plugin id 'ExampleApp'?

Comment: @greg-449 Well this is part of a much larger project that is being interfaced with. We are setting up an "ExampleApp" to test some functionality. But yes, it is an entire eclipse project in itself.

Comment: Show us the plugin MANIFEST.MF and your .product file.

Comment: @greg-449 Files pasted here

Answer (score 2):

Your MANIFEST.MF says the plugin id ('Bundle-SymbolicName') is `CyAMSApp`, so the product id declared by the plugin.xml is `CyAMSApp.product`.

Change the 'Bundle-SymbolicName' to be 'ExampleApp' or change the references to the product id to be 'CyAMSApp.product'.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

These two files must be compared from the other environment where it is working you try checking the files existence first and if they exist then check the configuration of the projects